# Hiding Address Bar on iPhone/Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

The script bellow is hiding the address bar on mobile, but is not hiding the address bar on display/desktop. This is the desired outcome, but I don't understand why this happening. I would have guessed this would have also hidden the address bar across all devices. Is there a better approach to hiding the address bar? Could some be as so kind to walk me through this?

I also read that I need to add the meta tag below into the header, but I don't think it is having an effect. Thanks for your input!

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" 


<script>
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  // Set a timeout...
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Hide the address bar!
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});

var preventDefault = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different techniques there.

The first says "This is a single page web application" so will open without an address bar on an iOS device *iff* launched from a Homescreen icon (which, obviously, requires that the user visit the page (with the address bar visible) and add it to the Homescreen).

The second just attempts to scroll the page up so that the address bar is scrolled off the screen. Mobile devices do this because they have small screens so they let the address bar scroll off the top of the screen. The user can easily scroll down to get it back.

Desktop browsers do not usually suffer from being displayed on a tiny screen, so they have no reason to hide it when scrolling. On the other hand, allowing the user to be aware of the address of the page they are currently visiting is a very important anti-phishing measure.

Consequently: There is no way for a website to conceal the address bar from the user in modern browsers.

Comment: It would be a potential security vulnerability too